# Create DRM content from mp3 files for exoplayer

Tags: exoplayer, drm

I am trying to create DRM content using shaka-packager to use it with exoplayer. With mp4 files it works well and exoplayer works fine. But when I try to create DRM content for a mp3 file it says that mp3 is not supported: `Unable to determine output format` Is there any other way to create DRM content for audio files or how can I use shapa-packager to do it?

This is the command I am using:

```
packager \
in=nothing_else_matters.mp3,stream=audio,output=audio.mp3 \
  --mpd_output sample.mpd \
  --enable_widevine_encryption \
  --key_server_url https://license.uat.widevine.com/cenc/getcontentkey/widevine_test \
  --content_id ############################### \
  --signer widevine_test \
  --aes_signing_key ####################################### \
  --aes_signing_iv #################################
```

And is working if I use with mp4 files like this:

```
packager \
in=test.mp4,stream=audio,output=audio.mp4 \
  in=test.mp4,stream=video,output=video.mp4 \
  --mpd_output sample.mpd \
  --enable_widevine_encryption \
  --key_server_url https://license.uat.widevine.com/cenc/getcontentkey/widevine_test \
  --content_id ######################## \
  --signer widevine_test \
  --aes_signing_key ################################# \
  --aes_signing_iv ####################
```

I also tried to convert the mp3 to mp4 and then use this command but it did't work.

Answer (score 0):

Shaka Packager does not support MP3 output at this time, AFAIK. This is the view also from their current documentation and looking at the GitHub source itself.

DRM technologies usually will have a cost for the stream provider if you are using one of the standard ones supported on all major devices - on Android it is typically Widevine.

As Audio is very hard to protect anyway, because it will generally be converted to analogue when it is played via the speakers or headphones, it may not make commercial sense to protect the audio files with DRM.

Many solutions will either use a URL obsfibciation or authentication approach, to make it harder to download the music without authorisation, and/or a simple file encryption approach with the key shared either in the app config or in some other secure, but not DRM based, way.

Some also add an audio watermark to allow you trace the source of the copying if someone does download and distribute your mp3.

If you do encrypt it using some file encryption approach, then on the player side you simply need to decrypt it as you receive it and pass it to the player.

As an aside, the ease with which audio can de decrypted is why DRM providers recommend using a separate key for audio than for video in video files (in fact the recommendation now is to use different keys for SD, HD, 4K video etc also). The logic is that if the audio is recorded and the key cracked by comparing the encrypted and unencrypted audio then the same key won't be able to be used to decrypt the video also.